# Is Office365 connectors useful if there is already a notifications service?

Tags: office365, office365connectors

I was reading about new [Office365 Connectors](https://dev.outlook.com/Connectors/ConnectButton)

As a summary,
Microsoft 365 "Connecters" allows o365 admin user to subscribe an o365 user group for notifications from a third party system (e.g. Zendesk, Mailchimp....). When o365 to 3rd Party app connection configured o365 platform provides a URL (Webhook URL) to the third party  app to push notifications (json messages), so that the 0365 users can get notifications without login to other apps.

My question is that ,if the **third party app** already has a Notification service which sends email notifications to users, is it useful to build a O365 connector which is more specific to 0365?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Office 365 Connectors for groups can be setup by any end user. Depending on your service and business, they are a couple of scenarios where Connectors make sense

1. Connectors helps everyone in the team stay connected and engaged with the 3rd party service. By using webhooks for Office 365 Groups, services can post content  directly to the shared group inbox space, keeping the team in sync and allowing them to have a conversation about the post.
2. Connectors provide 3rd party services an option to provide granular user controls during the configuration or setup of a connector. This allows users to choose the information & content they care about and decide the frequency of those updates
3. Connectors are simple to build and it takes care of the UI/UX for you. Based on the JSON, it automatically renders the card in Outlook. The experience is broadly available in Outlook 2016, Outlook on the web and shortly in Groups mobile app for iOS and Android.  This ensures the 3rd party content looks great in all the Outlook clients including mobile.
4. The 3rd party service logo and brand is shown on the card and the sender picture in Outlook. 3rd party services can use markdown and images to richly enhance the look and feel of the card.  The cards help surface important and relevant content and empower users with actions - allowing a 2 way user interaction with the service
5. The platform provide broad distribution by allowing 3rd party Connectors to get published and listed in the Office 365 Group in-product catalog. Over 60 connectors are available to Office 365 users today through this catalog -- from collaborating on a coding project using the GitHub connector, to tracking feedback in Uservoice, monitoring your project activities in Asana and many more, serving various categories like CRM, social, news, HR, IT, marketing and productivity. Check out some of the connectors integrations for more ideas